# I need to find the surface area between Sphere : $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the Cylinder : $x^2 + y^2 = x$

Tags: calculus

I'm new to calculus and I tried to do this example but I wasn't able to. I need to find the area between the sphere : $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the cylinder : $x^2 + y^2 = x$.

I tried to rewrite the cylinder as $(x-1/2)^2 + y^2 = 1/4$ and I got after that $y^2 = x-x^2$ and substitued in the sphere equation, and I got $z^2 = 1 - x$.

I need to find the surface area which represents the intersection of the sphere and the cylinder.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know some rules to solve it?

Comment: I tried to rewrite the cylinder as (x-1/2)^2 + y^2 = 1/4 and I got after that y^2 = x-x^2 and substitued in the sphere equation, and I got z^2 = 1 - x.

Comment: @Robert-AndreiTănăsescu do you need the *volume*?

Comment: Are you sure you want the surface area and not the volume? Do you mean the area of the patch of the sphere that is inside the cylinder? I didn't quite understand your question

Comment: Please add any clarifications to the body of the question, not the comments.  People browsing questions don't see comments.  Also, in order for the MathJax to take effect, you have to enclose it in `$` signs.  Welcome to MSE!

Comment: I don't know if any of these alternative equations will help but they might provide hints at a solution.
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1\implies x^2+y^2=1-z^2$$
Given $\qquad \qquad \qquad x^2+y^2=x\implies x=1-z^2$
$$x^2-x+y^2=0\implies x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2}$$